# Failure/Error: visit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, lambda

Can anyone tell me what is the meaning of this error:

> > Failure/Error: visit new_user_registration_path
> >          NameError:
> >            undefined local variable or method `new_user_registration_path' for #
> >          # ./spec/controllers/user_controller_spec.rb:10
> >          # ./spec/controllers/user_controller_spec.rb:9

the errors are only on the function "lambda" of my spec look:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User" do

describe "signup" do

describe "failure" do
  it "should not make a new user" do
    lambda do
      visit new_user_registration_path
      fill_in "email",        :with => ""
      fill_in "password",     :with => ""
      fill_in "password_confirmation", :with => ""
      click_button
      response.should render_template('users/new')
      response.should have_selector('div#error_explanation')
    end.should_not change(User, :count)
  end
end
....
```

my routes rake says that the new_user_registration exist look

```
   cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                  devise/registrations#cancel
   user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                        devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                devise/registrations#new
   edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                   devise/registrations#edit
...
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Just replace:

```
new_user_registration
```

With:

```
new_user_registration_path
```

Comment: still nothing I changed it but appears the same error... I mean appears the same error but with  >Failure/Error: visit new_user_registration_path

Comment: ok get it: you put the test in your controller specs, it should live in the requests specs where it will work since the proper modules will be included.

Comment: Failure/Error: fill_in "email", :with => ""
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       cannot fill in, no text field, text area or password field with id, name, or label 'email' found

Comment: Well, the error is self explanatory. I highly recommend you use something like 'launchy' and use the 'save_and_open_page' to see the page you're actually working on. Will save you time.

Comment: try replace lambda with expect{ ... YOUR CODE ....}.should_not change(User, :count)